# GRUB does not want to boot from my USB stick's second partition. How to fix?

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a 64 GB USB stick with four partitions:

1. FAT for data transfer with Windows
2. Linux bootable
3. Encrypted Linux partition
4. Linux partition

The booting from the bootable partition worked fine
on most computers. 
(Didn't work on an old MacBook with Intel CPU.)

I found an old laptop and tried to reinstall Linux via the bootable partition,
but the F12 Menu could not find it (USB stick).

So I got into GRUB and typed:

```
grub>ls
(proc) (hd0) (hd0,msdos1)  (hd0,msdos2)  (hd0,msdos3)  (hd0,msdos4)  (hd1,gpt1) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt4)
```

I found out that the right partition is “`(hd0,msdos2)`”.

```
Partition hd0,msdos2: Filesystem type iso9660 - Label 'EOS_202209' - ...
```

and searched by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> for the `.EFI` file:

```
set root=(hd0,msdos2)/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI
```

This file definitely exists and GRUB can see it, since it led me to it:

```
grub> chainloader +1

error: disk ‘(hd0,msdos2)/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI’ not found.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PC world, there are currently two boot methods, the classic BIOS method, and the modern UEFI one. `.EFI` files are for the UEFI boot method only; an old laptop might only support the classic BIOS method. GRUB has separate architecture versions: `i386-pc` for classic BIOS boot, and `x86_64-efi` for UEFI.

The GRUB `root` variable should identify a partition, LVM logical volume or other filesystem container; not an individual file. `chainloader +1` tells GRUB to read and execute the code in the first disk block off the partition identified by the `root` variable, and would be an appropriate command for chainloading the Windows bootloader for the BIOS boot method.

For UEFI, to run an .EFI file you would something like this:

```
set root=(hd0,msdos2)
chainloader /EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI
```

But that would most likely just manually repeat the part of the boot process that already brought you into GRUB in the first place.

If you want to boot Linux (or its installer), you don't want to run any more .EFI files once you have reached GRUB: you want to load a kernel file (typically with a command like `linux vmlinuz-<version number>`) and probably an initramfs/initrd file: its naming varies between distributions, but on Mint (a relative of Debian) the command would look like `initrd initrd.img-<kernel version number>`.

The filesystem label `EOS_202209` suggests what you have is probably EndeavourOS, which is based on Arch, so I'm not sure why you're even mentioning Linux Mint.